# async/await not working and i dont see why

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

```
function projectHTML(e) {
  let proj = await getProject(e.srcElement.dataset.id);
  console.log(proj);
  return `
    <div id="Project">
      <h1>${proj.name}</h1>
      <p>Description: ${proj.description}</p>
    </div>
  `;
}

async function getProject(id) {
  try {
    let res = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/projects/${id}`);
    res = await res.json();
    return res;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

The first function, `projectHTML()`, is being called from another file. I am able to return the value from function `gethelp()`, `ProjectsHTML()`. I can even log it in the console and indeed see it's correct. However, it won't load up into the template literal that I have. Please, someone lend a hand. I tried doing `async...await` in try blocks in `ProjectsHTML()` and still no luck.

[Image of web issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeVe1.png)

Comment: Seems it need to be `async function  projectHTML`

Comment: The code should not even run at the moment. `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Answer (score 2):

## Function

```
async function getProject(id) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/projects/${id}`);
    return res.json();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

## Call

```
getProject(id).then((data) => { 
  console.log(data) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code like following:

```
async function projectHTML(e) {

let proj = await getProject(e.srcElement.dataset.id);
console.log(proj)
return `<div id="Project">
            <h1>${proj.name}</h1>
            <p>Description: ${proj.description}</p>
        </div>`;
};
```

If I am not wrong above function is an event handler and you are using passing it in your `html`. If not, and you are calling it from another function, you need to use `await`while calling this function:

`await projectHtml(e)`

Let me know if this helps.